# c++ alternative to macro for compile-time string literal concatenation

Tags: c++, c++03

I want to concatenate a number of string literals at compile time:

```
#include <iostream>

#define VAR0 "var0 text"
#define VAR1 "var1 text"
#define VAR2 "var2 text"

static const char* concat = "var0:" VAR0 " var1:" VAR1 " var2:" VAR2 ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << concat << std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

This is all very well, but I'd rather use constant expressions instead of macros. Is there any simple  way of doing this in C++ 03?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ template string concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693819/c-template-string-concatenation)

Comment: @icepack: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately the possible duplicate is tagged as C++11. It starts from the premise of variadic templates. I'm looking for a C++03 solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's only possible to concatenate *literals*. There is no way to concatenate generic constant char array expressions in C++03. It is, however, possible to concatenate weird template abominations `boost::mpl::string` from [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/)