# Is there a way to write a BSTR literal?

Tags: c++, c++builder, bstr

When calling a function that expects a BSTR it'd be nice to be able to write something like:

```
iFoo->function( bs"HELLO" );
```

However the only workaround I'm aware of is to use a wrapper that calls `SysAllocString` etc., e.g.:

```
iFoo->function( WideString(L"HELLO").c_bstr() );
```

which is kind of ugly.  Is there actually such an option to create a `BSTR` literal?

Motivation: easier-to-read code, and faster runtime performance by avoiding an allocation and deallocation.

**Clarification:** I am only talking about situations where the caller (i.e. us) has ownership of the BSTR, for example: calling a function that takes a `BSTR [in]` parameter. Of course, it would be silly to supply a pointer to a BSTR literal to a function which will go on to try and free the string.

Comment: A very ugly solution is `L"\xA\0" "HELLO" + 2`

Comment: Not only ugly, wait until someone calls `SysFreeString()` on that :)

Comment: BSTR's are by-definition dynamic managed. The concept could certainly be tossed into a literal, but it wouldn't be a BSTR. And it would be disastrous if ever used in a place where it was eventually free'd. The OLE libs have *many* places (variant functions, marshaller code, etc) where things like VARIANT members are managed behind the scenes. Placement of something like this in such a place would be disastrous. You could always punt and just use any of the canned BSTR smart pointer classes like `bstr_t` or `CComBSTR`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Functions that accept BSTR shouldn't be freeing it (i.e. memory is managed by the caller), this is the same as complaining that you can't do `printf("hello");` because `printf` might free the string!

Comment: @WhozCraig If the called function does free the string (and we did not use the literal I am suggesting) it'd break the program anyway as there would be a double free.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Why would you free a BSTR that is being freed already? `VariantChangeType` for example, Called from a loaded `VARIANT` with a "literal" invalid BSTR for "1000" changing to `VT_LONG` would be UB from the rafters. BSTR `[in,out]` marshalling by-definition will free the input `BSTR` and replace it with an output-BSTR *multiple times*. There is **zero** sense in literal BSTRs. I just reread your comment and I *think* you agree. I concur, something being sent a `[in] BSTR` should not be freeing it (except `SysFreeString` of course).

Comment: @WhozCraig When creating a VARIANT that owns its BSTR you would allocate one. BSTRs have well defined ownership semantics. Only the owner should free the string. There is no `[in, out] BSTR`, only `BSTR *` which has callee-ownership.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Declaring `[in,out] BSTR` in MIDL will create `BSTR *` in the generated header and proxy/stub (it did last I checked anyway; been awhile). I completely agree its all about ownership.

Comment: @WhozCraig OK, so when it is a caller-ownership situation then why shouldn't the caller be able to use a literal in order to avoid wasting time with an allocation and deallocation?

Comment: Answering my own question... I guess that some memory checker tool might try and check that any pointer supplied to a function expecting BSTRs actually corresponds with something that exists in the OLE allocation table

Comment: @MattMcNabb *that* is a good question. Since everything- `BSTR` is supposed to play by the rules, how it is *built* is not up to you; its up to MS. They [document them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx), which is nice, but they're also free to *change* that. Trying to literalize that is easily, if not more, tedious than just playing by the rules. Ex: your proposed "very ugly" solution is *not* conforming (it doesn't have two terminating nulls). Why would *you* want to do that? And you can toss BSTR-caching, which COM does for you, out entirely.

Comment: Great brain-food, btw. uptick =P

Comment: @WhozCraig I always took "two null characters" to mean two null narrow characters (i.e. one null wide character) - because requiring two null wide characters is just too strange! :)

Comment: It caught me somewhat by surprise as well, since the rest of the documentation freely interchanges "characters" with wide or narrow depending on the context. I wish I had a Windows box to verify, but as memory serves there are 32-bits of nothingness at the end of a valid BSTR. If you have one handy (a windows box) I'm truly curious which it is. Otherwise I'll check tomorrow at work and report back.

Comment: @WhozCraig Tried it just now , [here is the result](http://i.imgur.com/lDpXxh9.png) ...

Comment: Definitely worth noting in your question imho. The ABABAB looks like typical MS debug fill. I humbly apologize for my inaccuracy. (and makes me wonder where *did* I see all those added octets). Now I'm genuinely curious if MS just ignores state-junk they may be keeping when given a non-rule-allocated `BSTR` in their functions. Good question!

Comment: @WhozCraig AB stands for allocated block i.e. an uninitialized memory block that was allocated with LocalAlloc().

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264616/c-create-bstr-at-compile-time-insert-length-into-string-at-compile-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow up on @MSalters's answer, a custom user-defined literal could look something like this:

```
CComBSTR operator "" _bstr (const char* str, std::size_t len)
{
    return CComBSTR(len, str);
}
```

Then you can do this (as `CComBSTR` has a `BSTR` conversion operator defined):

```
iFoo->function( "HELLO"_bstr );
```

You can even overload the operator for multiple input string literal types:

```
CComBSTR operator "" _bstr (const wchar_t* str, std::size_t len)
{
    return CComBSTR(len, str);
}

CComBSTR operator "" _bstr (const char16_t* str, std::size_t len)
{
    return CComBSTR(len, (wchar_t*)str);
}
```

```
iFoo->function( L"HELLO"_bstr ); // calls wchar_t* version with UTF-16 encoded data

iFoo->function( u"HELLO"_bstr ); // calls char16_t* version with UTF-16 encoded data

iFoo->function( u8"HELLO"_bstr ); // calls char* version with UTF-8 encoded data...
```

Note the last case.  Since the operator will not know whether it is being passed ANSI or UTF-8 data, and `CComBSTR` assumes ANSI when passed `char*` data,  you should use a different literal suffix to differentiate so you can convert the UTF-8 correctly, eg:

```
CComBSTR operator "" _utf8bstr (const char* str, std::size_t len)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
    std::wstring wstr = conv.from_bytes(std::string(str, len));
    return CComBSTR(wstr.length(), wstr.c_str());
}

iFoo->function( u8"HELLO"_utf8bstr );
```

Comment: This actually looks like a good case for user-defined literals.

Comment: One must be careful not to write `BSTR b = "hello"_bstr;`

Comment: Yup, you would have to use `CComBSTR b = "hello"_bstr;` or better `auto b = "hello"_bstr;` instead.

Answer (score 4):

User defined literals would be the way to go:

`"HELLO"_bstr` calls `template<char...> BSTR operator "" _bstr ( const char*, std::size_t)` which can then call `SysAllocString()`

New in VS14.

[edit]

Based on the comments, it might be better to return a `_bstr_t` or other class which takes ownership of the `SysAllocString()` result and implicitly converts to `BSTR`. This temporary will be destroyed at the end of the full expression, and therefore *after* `iFoo->function( "HELLO"_bstr );` returns.

Comment: That solves the "ugly syntax" problem, although it causes a memory leak   if used like `iFoo->function( "hello"_bstr );`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Isn't the destructor called when `iFoo->function` returns?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I'd have to check the exact rules. It's fixable by returning a temporary which implicitly converts to `BSTR` but frees the string afterwards. But I thought that passing a BSTR implies passing ownership.

Comment: @TonyK: A `BSTR` is just a pointer, there is no destructor to call if the operator returns a `BSTR` directly. You would have to make the operator return an instance of a class instead, and that class could have a `BSTR` conversion operator defined.

Comment: @MSalters: simply passing a `BSTR` does not imply passing ownership. It depends on the contract of the parameter. If the parameter is marked as `[out]` or `[out,retval]`, the function allocates the `BSTR` and passes ownership to the caller. If the parameter is marked as `[in,out]`, the function is allowed to reallocate the source `BSTR`, and the caller maintains ownership of whatever the `BSTR` is set to upon exit. If the parameter is marked as `[in]`, ownership is not changed at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yikes, that explains why I didn't remember the exact rules. And it also looks like typical C: type-safe in name only, one type with multiple different behaviors. `[out]` is de facto not part of the type system. I don't think it ever makes sense to pass a "BSTR literal" to an `[out]` argument, yet the compiler has no way to prevent it.

Comment: @MSalters: a parameter marked with `[out]` must be passed by address, not by value. So you would not be able to pass a `BSTR` to an `[out]` parameter because it is expecting a `BSTR*` instead. So a custom `operator "" _bstr` that returns a `BSTR` (directly or otherwise) would only be usable with `[in]` parameters anyway.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Ok, then my idea of a temporary object with implicit conversion to `BSTR` and destruction on exit is indeed safe.

Comment: @MSalters: yes, it is.  I have added an example to demonstrate it.