# Generating C++ typename by concatenating template parameter with a string

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I'm trying to figure out a way to use Boost::MPL to generate a typename which is the concatenation of a template parameter and a string.

I have pairs of classes which are named: `X` and `XProvider`.  The latter is a factory class which instantiates objects inherited from the former type.

The template class is intended to manage the instantiation of types at runtime: it contains, among other things, an unordered_map and some other misc. members.

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is a metafunction that looks something like this:

Given the class

```
template <typename T>
class Plugin_Manager{

    using Base_Type = T;

    std::vector<Get_Provider_Type<Base_Type>::type *> m_provider_collection;

      */ ... /*

};
```

Where `Get_Provider_Type<T>` is a metafunction which returns a typename TProvider.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693819/c-template-string-concatenation?lq=1), I think that the metafunction should look something along the lines of this:

```
    template < typename Str1, typename Str2 >
    struct concat : boost::mpl::insert_range < Str1, typename boost::mpl::end<Str1>::type, Str2 > {};


    template <class T> struct Get_Provider_Type{
        typedef typename boost::mpl::string<boost::mpl::c_str<T>::value>::type Base_Name;
        typedef boost::mpl::string<'Prov', 'ider'> Suffix;

        typedef typename concat<Base_Name, Suffix>::type type;
    };
```

However, I am really not understanding `mpl::c_str` or `mpl::string` or their correct usage, and I cannot follow the error messages that I am receiving.  The code as written above gives me the error message:

```
    error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of 'foo'
```

(foo here being the template argument --  `Plugin_Manager<foo>`)

I realize that I can likely make this work if I use a large macro rather than c++ template, but I would **really** like to avoid that if **at all** possible.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks-
Shmuel

Comment: Macros are the only way to create new identifiers by combining existing ones, sorry. Templates can't do it.

Comment: What you are saying does not make much sense to me. If you intend to use the expression `Get_provider_Type<Base_Type>::type` to specify the template argument of a vector all you need is to provide a type. You don't need to generate a name for it at all.

Comment: Perhaps _generate_ is the wrong term.  `Plugin_Manager<foo>` needs to contain a `std::vector<fooProvider>` -- I'd like to have a metafunction `Get_Provider_Type<foo>::type` which will return for me the type `fooProvider`, but I do not know how to write this metafunction (or even if it's possible -- per @MarkRansom's comment above).

Comment: @ShmuelLevine It's not possible. It might be better to simply provide a `public: typedef fooProvider provider;` inside of `foo`. This way each class can define their own provider type and don't have to follow any particular naming convention. Then you just have `typename T::provider` as the provider type.

Comment: @cdhowie, all-in-all, that is a sensible approach, and since it only needs to be in the base class, it has a minimal impact.  I don't know why I didn't think of this beforehand... I guess I've had TMP on my mind lately and looking to learn a little more than I did yesterday...

Comment: @ShmuelLevine *"it only needs to be in the base class"* -- I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean here, but if I do then this may not be true.  If you have `class bar : public foo` and `boo` needs its own `barProvider` then you need to shadow the `provider` typedef in `bar` to get the right behavior.

Comment: @cdhowie, `barProvider` itself is derived from `fooProvider`.  The notation xxxProvider is consistent throughout, but in all cases, wherever I have `bar : public foo`, I will also have `barProvider : public fooProvider`.  That is the convention that is used in [this framework](http://pluma-framework.sourceforge.net/) which I have been tryign to use to deal with the boilerplate code.

Comment: @ShmuelLevine Right but if you only put `typedef fooProvider provider;` in `foo`, then `bar::provider` is `fooProvider`. You need the typedef at each level to point to the right provider type. `bar::provider` won't magically become `barProvider` just because `barProvider` derives `fooProvider`.

Comment: @cdhowie Right.  Of course it will not magically become barProvider; however, in this context, it is accessed polymorphically through fooProvider*.  I intended my comment -- that adding the `typedef fooProvider provider;` will suffice -- to be specific to my own application, not in the general sense.

Comment: @ShmuelLevine Right, okay -- as long as you aren't using `T::provider` to actually *construct* the provider object. (I can't see your code so I assume based on what you've said that this isn't the case.) Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't get a typename from concatenating strings with template parameters, but if your intention is...

> I'd like to have a metafunction Get_Provider_Type::type which will return for me the type fooProvider

You can simply define the type in `foo`:

```
struct foo {
    using provider = fooProvider;
};
```

If you need it, you can implement your "metafunction" that will work with all types that define `T::provider`

```
template<class T>
struct Get_Provider_Type {
    using type = typename T::provider;
};
```

Which can be useful if you can't modify `foo` to define the type. Then you can specialize `Get_Provider_Type` instead:

```
template<>
struct Get_Provider_Type<foo> {
    using type = fooProvider;
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why I didn't think of this approach before.  It is elegant and will work surprisingly well for my specific application (as mentioned in the comments above on my original post).  I guess I had my mind set on finding a solution with mpl and concatenation so this didn't even occur to me.  Thanks!

Comment: I thought C++'s template system was Turing-complete?  Doesn't that imply that there is some way to do it?